# How to split a number from end to start

Tags: php, string, split

How could I split a number from end to start?

Considering that the number can have any length.

The closest thing I tried:

```
$str = "1234"; #or any other number/string ranging from 0 - 99999
#then somehow inverse the number
$arr1 = str_split($str);

if(!empty($arr1[0])){echo "<div ...>".$arr1[0]."</div>";}
if(!empty($arr1[1])){echo "<div ...>".$arr1[1]."</div>";}
if(!empty($arr1[2])){echo "<div ...>".$arr1[2]."</div>";}
if(!empty($arr1[3])){echo "<div ...>".$arr1[3]."</div>";}
if(!empty($arr1[4])){echo "<div ...>".$arr1[4]."</div>";}
```

Thank you.

Comment: To start with, look at foreach() loops

Comment: Have you looked at the string handling function in php before asking your question? If not, do so now please. Also, please clarify what you mean by inverse. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't use a loop because I want to display also the zeros instead of the value: 01234

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [strrev](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) function like this:

```
<?php
    $rev = strrev($str);
?>
```

**Update: One liner to do it all:**

```
$reverse = 
array_map(create_function('$n','return "<div...>$n</div>";'), str_split(strrev($str)));
```

Comment: thank you @anubhava<?php
  
  $rev = strrev($km);
      $number = str_split($rev);$kmi = 0;
      foreach ($number as $value) {
     echo "<div class='right km_digit'>".$value."</div>"; $kmi++;
  }
  $loop = 4 - $kmi;
  for($i=0; $i<= $loop; $i++){
   echo "<div class='right km_digit'>0</div>";
  }
  
  ?>

Answer (score 2):

```
$number = 1234567; 
$number = str_split($n);
$numbers = array_reverse($number);
```

The `$number` variable is converted to a string if it is not already before being split. Then the array is reversed.

To loop through it:

```
foreach ($numbers as $value) {
    echo "<div ...>".$value."</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the length and using the for loop you can extract the numbers one by one.

You can find the length using `strlen()` and `for loop` upto `strlen()`

```
$str = "1234";
$str = strrev($str);
for($i=0; $i<= strlen($str); $i++){

 echo substr($str,$i,1)."<br>";
}
```